# How to add HtmlGenericControl to a HtmlNode?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, htmlgenericcontrol

I'm stuck,
this must be very simple to accomplish but i'm not seeing how.

I have this code:

```
 var divEl = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='" + field.Id + "']");

 var newdiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
 newdiv.Attributes.Add("id", label.ID);
 newdiv.Attributes.Add("text", label.Text);
 newdiv.Attributes.Add("class", label.CssClass);
```

And i need to do something like this:

```
    divEl.AppendChild(newdiv); //not working its expecting a HtmlNode, not a HtmlGenericControl
```

How can i convert this?

Thanks for any response in advance,
chapas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below. you will need to make some changes. controls innerHTML is well formed and can be used as innerXML for an xmlNode

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
//Load your xml here TODO
var divEl = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='test']"); //Change your xpath here TODO
var newdiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div"); 
newdiv.Attributes.Add("id", "id"); 
newdiv.Attributes.Add("text", "text"); 
newdiv.Attributes.Add("class", "class");

XmlNode newNode = doc.CreateNode("NodeType", "NodeName", "URI/if/any"); //update your variables here
newNode.InnerXml = newdiv.InnerHtml;
divEl.AppendChild(newNode);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create the node using HAP's API instead?  It should work very similarly.

```
var newDiv = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<div/>");
newDiv.Attributes.Add("id", label.ID);
newDiv.Attributes.Add("text", label.Text);
newDiv.Attributes.Add("class", label.CssClass);

divEl.AppendChild(newDiv);
```

There is no easy way to get the outer HTML of the `HtmlGenericControl` instance (AFAIK).  If you had it, you could just pass the HTML in to the `HtmlNode.CreateNode()` method to create it.  But I would strongly suggest not trying to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a way to get your OuterHtml from HtmlGenericControl:

```
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    using (HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(textWriter))
    {
        HtmlGenericControl control = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

        control.Attributes.Add("One", "1");
        control.Attributes.Add("Two", "2");
        control.InnerText = "Testing 123";

        control.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    }
}
```

the textWriter.ToString() will get you following:

```
<div One="1" Two="2">Testing 123</div>
```